# Is it possible to use assignment in a if statement?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'd like to do something like below in Python 3:

```py
import re

s = "abcde"

if match = re.search("abc(de)", s):
    print(match.group(1))
elif match = re.search("abc(fg)", s):
    print(match.group(1))
elif match = re.search("abc(hi)", s):
    print(match.group(1))
...
```

However, Python does not allow assignment in the condition clause of `if` statement and the code above cannot be executed.

How can I achieve this goal without getting errors? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Assign to match outside the conditional

Comment: Fundamentally, the problem is that assignment statements are *not expressions* in Python, and don't evaluate to anything. This is different than say, C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can represent the regex patterns in better ways to perform this.

Something like:

```
match = re.search("abc(de|fg|hi)", s)

if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

If your regex patterns are slightly more complex, you can loop through the patterns to match individually and check:

```
patterns = [r"abc(de)", r"abc(fg)", r"abc(hi)"]

for pattern in patterns:
    match = re.search(pattern, s)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is very clean and clear. It gives me a great insight.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, nope, you can only use expressions in your `if` statements. But you can delegate if you really want to do it:

```
import re

_delegate = None
def delegate_search(pattern=None, data=None):
    global _delegate
    if pattern is None:
        delegate = _delegate
        _delegate = None
        return delegate
    _delegate = delegate = re.search(pattern, data)
    return delegate

s = "abcde"

if delegate_search("abc(de)", s):
    print(delegate_search().group(1))
elif delegate_search("abc(fg)", s):
    print(delegate_search().group(1))
elif delegate_search("abc(hi)", s):
    print(delegate_search().group(1))
```

And you can even use some *magic* to make it look as if you're not calling a function, but it's just silly to use it this way.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is the closest to what I originally wanted, although it is a bit tedious in Python as you mentioned. Anyway, this is a great idea, too.